# E0312 IntelliSense Cannot convert _Binder

Tags: c++, templates, event-handling, partial-specialization

I am trying to make an Event Handler system on my project, and it is already working as expected, but the IDE are accusing an error  that I have no idea how to solve. As I said, everything is working, compiling and running normally, but I would like to solve this issue from IntelliSense.
Defining Events:

```
enum class RendererEvents
{
    Render,
    PostRender
};

struct RenderArgs
{
};

struct PostRenderArgs
{
};

template<typename T> struct EventArgsFn { using type = T; };

template<>
struct EventArgsFn<RendererEvents>
{
    using type = std::variant<std::function<void(RenderArgs&)>, std::function<void(PostRenderArgs&)>>;
};
```

Event Handler:

```
template<typename T>
class EventProvider
{
public:
    /// Subscribe Event with Arguments.
    void SubscribeEventArgs(T EventType, typename EventArgsFn<T>::type Fn)
    {
        m_EventsArgs[EventType].push_back(Fn);
    }

private:
    /// Events Handler with Arguments.
    std::unordered_map<T, std::vector<typename EventArgsFn<T>::type>> m_EventsArgs;
};
```

Using the Subscribe Event function (where is giving the "error"):

```
Renderer.SubscribeEventArgs(Graphics::RendererEvents::Render, std::bind(&Teste3, std::placeholders::_1));
```

The error that are giving:

```
Cannot convert _Binder<_Unforced, void(*)(Graphics::RenderArgs&), const _Ph<1>&> to parameter type EventArgsFn<Graphics::RendererEvents>::type
```

Anyone have any idea what's happening if there is some way to suppress this error or solve?
Thanks!

Comment: void Teste3(RenderArgs& Args)

Comment: Free function. Really weird, are you using Visual Studio? Here with VS 10.9.2 and C++ 17 IntelliSense show it as error but I can compile and run normally.